# timestamp in PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp, milliseconds

I have this timestamp how to convert it to unix timestamp

```
1.6749018E+12
```

Or is there any way to decode it in PHP let me know.
have good day!

My code

```
$t = '1.6749018E+12';
print date('H:i:s', $t);
```

Not work!

Answer (score 1):

`1.6749018E+12` looks like a unix time with milliseconds as float number. If I'm right, then the conversion to a unix time in seconds is:

```
$unixtime = intval($NUMBER/1000)
```

where `$NUMBER` is the input number (`1.6749018E+12` in you example). This number represents: `Sat Jan 28 11:30:00 CET 2023` (or `10:30 UTC`).